# How to simplify this code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I’ve just started learning canvas and have tried so far a couple of exercises, but my code is always way too long and most probably unnecessarily complicated. I have the following code of a four leaf clover drawing and would like to know how to simplify it. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

```
var clover = document.getElementById("clover");
var ctx = clover.getContext("2d");

//style:

ctx.strokeStyle = "#006600";
ctx.lineWidth = 0.3;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,100,200,100,235,135);
ctx.stroke();

//First leaf:

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 0.8;

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(55,70);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20,100,115,80);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(55,70);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(40,30,115,80);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//  Second leaf:

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(80,20,130,50);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(200,40,130,50);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//  Third leaf:

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(235,60,185,85);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(190,115,185,85);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//  Fourth leaf:

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(180,135,110,115);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "#7BA32D";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115,80);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(60,130,110,115);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//  lines on the leaves:

ctx.strokeStyle = "#006600";
ctx.lineWidth = 0.3;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115, 80);
ctx.lineTo(65, 71);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115, 80);
ctx.lineTo(127, 55);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115, 80);
ctx.lineTo(175, 85);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115, 80);
ctx.lineTo(110, 110);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: Try to place similar code blocks in a loop and get the values that change from an array or similar. Shouldn’t be that hard.

Answer (score 4):

Write one or more functions that do the things you are repeating. Figure out what parameters they need to take to be able to handle the slightly different cases. Then call the functions with the right parameters. For example, your code of the form

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(115, 80);
ctx.lineTo(110, 110);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

would be written as the function

```
function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

and called as

```
line(115, 80, 110, 110);
```

Comment: Nope `beginPath` has to be there. Your answer would be better without this note. However, `closePath` after the `stroke` is useless, `fill` already perform internally this `closePath`, which is just a `lineTo(previousMovedPoint)`. And instead of calling it `draw`, a better name could be `line` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Expressive language

Javascript is known for its expressive flexibility and can allow coding styles not found in most other languages.

#### Use Path2D

The first thought for your code was to use the Path2D object to define the draw commands. It uses similar syntax to SVG path command.

But why not create your own command list.

#### Named styles

First let's find all the styles and name them

```
var styles = {
    dGreen : {
        strokeStyle : "#006600",
        lineWidth : 0.3,
    },
    black : {
        strokeStyle : "black",
        fillStyle : "#7BA32D",
        lineWidth : 0.8,
    }
}
```

Now you can use the named style and if you name the properties the same as used by the 2D API it is very easy to set a style

```
function setStyle(style){
    Object.keys(style).forEach(prop => ctx[prop] = style[prop]); 
}, 

setStyle(styles.black); // sets the style black
```

If you want to use properties you did not think of at the time you dont have to code it just set the property and you are done

```
styles.black.lineJoin = "round";
setStyle(styles.black); // sets the style black
```

#### Custom command list.

For the drawing commands you are doing the same set of operations  many times. In SVG the commands are single characters "M" for moveto followed by x, y coordinates.

We can do the same. The commands will be a string, separated by "," which is then split into an array. You shift from the array each command as needed.

First the command object that has a function for each command. In this case `M` for moveTo and "L" for lineTo. It takes the array which it uses to get the coordinates from.

```
var commands = {
    M(array){
        ctx.moveTo(array.shift(),array.shift());
   },
   L(array){
        ctx.lineTo(array.shift(),array.shift());
   }

}
```

Then Define a path with our new commands move to 10,10 then line to 100,100

```
var path = "M,10,10,L,100,100";
```

Now we just need to parse and interpret the path

```
function drawPath(path){
    // split the command string into parts
    var commandList = path.split(",");
    // while there are commands
    while(commandList.length > 0){
         // use the next command to index the command
         // and call the function it names passing the command list so
         // it can get the data it needs
         commands[commandList.shift()](commandList);
    } // do that until there is nothing on the command list
}
```

Now all you need to do is supply the command strings to draw what you need. Because you can define the commands you can create commands as complex or simple as you want.

#### A little more complex

The following is the command functions and draw function I created to draw your image

```
// define draw commands
var drawFuncs = {
    getN(a,count){ return a.splice(0,count); },        // gets values from array
    M(a){ ctx.moveTo(...this.getN(a,2)); },          // move to
    C(a){ ctx.bezierCurveTo(...this.getN(a,6)); },   // bezier curve
    Q(a){ ctx.quadraticCurveTo(...this.getN(a,4)); },// quad curve
    S(){ ctx.stroke(); },                            // stroke
    P(){ ctx.closePath(); },                         // close path
    F(){ ctx.fill(); },                              // fill
    B(){ ctx.beginPath(); },                         // begin path
    l(a) {                                           // line segment
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(...this.getN(a,2));
        ctx.lineTo(...this.getN(a,2));
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    St(a){                                           // set style
        var style = styles[a.shift()];
        Object.keys(style).forEach(prop=>ctx[prop] = style[prop]); 
    }, 
}
// Takes command string and draws what is in it        
function draw(shape){
    var a = shape.split(",");
    while(a.length > 0){
        drawFuncs[a.shift()](a);
    }
}
```

You can put that code into a separate library and forget about it, while you concentrate on the rendering

Now you can render via your own custom made declarative language

Define the styles

```
// define named styles
var styles = {
    dGreen : {
        strokeStyle : "#006600",
        lineWidth : 0.3,
    },
    black : {
        strokeStyle : "black",
        fillStyle : "#7BA32D",
        lineWidth : 0.8,
    }
}
```

Create command list and draw

```
draw([
    "St,dGreen,B,M,115,80,C,20,100,200,100,235,135,S",
    "St,black,B,M,55,70,Q,20,100,115,80",
    "M,55,70,Q,40,30,115,80",
    "M,115,80,Q,80,20,130,50",
    "M,115,80,Q,200,40,130,50",
    "M,115,80,Q,235,60,185,85",
    "M,115,80,Q,190,115,185,85",
    "M,115,80,Q,180,135,110,115",
    "M,115,80,Q,60,130,110,115,S,P,F",
    "St,dGreen",
    "l,115,80,65,71",
    "l,115,80,127,55",
    "l,115,80,175,85",
    "l,115,80,110,110",
].join(","));
```

#### Demo

> Note: All the code is written in ES6 and will need Babel (or similar) to work on legacy browsers.

```js
    // define draw commands
    var drawFuncs = {
        getN(a,count){ return a.splice(0,count); },        // gets values from array
        M(a){ ctx.moveTo(...this.getN(a,2)); },          // move to
        C(a){ ctx.bezierCurveTo(...this.getN(a,6)); },   // bezier curve
        Q(a){ ctx.quadraticCurveTo(...this.getN(a,4)); },// quad curve
        S(){ ctx.stroke(); },                            // stroke
        P(){ ctx.closePath(); },                         // close path
        F(){ ctx.fill(); },                              // fill
        B(){ ctx.beginPath(); },                         // begin path
        l(a) {                                           // line segment
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(...this.getN(a,2));
            ctx.lineTo(...this.getN(a,2));
            ctx.stroke();
        },
        St(a){                                           // set style
            var style = styles[a.shift()];
            Object.keys(style).forEach(prop=>ctx[prop] = style[prop]); 
        }, 
    }
    // Takes command string and draws what is in it        
    function draw(shape){
        var a = shape.split(",");
        while(a.length > 0){
            drawFuncs[a.shift()](a);
        }
    }
    
    
    // create canvas and add to DOM
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    
    
    // define named styles
    var styles = {
        dGreen : {
            strokeStyle : "#006600",
            lineWidth : 0.3,
        },
        black : {
            strokeStyle : "black",
            fillStyle : "#7BA32D",
            lineWidth : 0.8,
        }
    }
    
    // draw it all
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw([
        "St,dGreen,B,M,115,80,C,20,100,200,100,235,135,S",
        "St,black,B,M,55,70,Q,20,100,115,80",
        "M,55,70,Q,40,30,115,80",
        "M,115,80,Q,80,20,130,50",
        "M,115,80,Q,200,40,130,50",
        "M,115,80,Q,235,60,185,85",
        "M,115,80,Q,190,115,185,85",
        "M,115,80,Q,180,135,110,115",
        "M,115,80,Q,60,130,110,115,S,P,F",
        "St,dGreen",
        "l,115,80,65, 71",
        "l,115,80,127, 55",
        "l,115,80,175, 85",
        "l,115,80,110, 110",
    ].join(","));
```